# Material ui Datepicker open on tab

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to open the Datepicker by pressing tab (when you are entering mutiple fields it is easy to use tab instead of clicking in the textbox) Only problem is i dont know how to do this:

```
<MobileDatePicker
  variant="outlined"
  label="Date of birth"
  disableFuture
  openTo="year"
  views={['year', 'month', 'date']}
  format="dd/MM/yyyy"
  value={dateOfBirth}
    onChange={e => {
    setDateOfBirth(e);
    setDateOfBirthError(false);
  }}
  error={dateOfBirthError !== false}
  helperText={dateOfBirthError}
  fullWidth
/>
```

anyone know how i can get this datepicker to open when i press tab?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onFocus` and controlled `open` prop in order to open it `onFocus`
But you likely want to have an accessible version of `DatePicker` so you can use v4.0.0-alpha version and `DesktopDatePicker` or just `DatePicker` in order to achieve built-in a11y

Comment: I am already using v4.0.0-alpha.4, and i want to force to use the mobiledatepicker and not the "normal" one for desktop so thats why i dont use DesktopDatePicker or DatePicker